# T-SQL: How to keep left join but filter query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to filter out results that were added by a specific user while keeping every day as this query will be used for a chart in a report. When I remove the `t2.createdBy <> 21` I get all of the dates but I also need the results to be filtered by this to be correct.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.DateFull, COUNT(t2.ContainerWashedDate) as Washes 
FROM 
    DateLookup t1
LEFT JOIN 
    factContainerWash t2 ON t1.Datefull = t2.ContainerWashedDate
WHERE 
    (t1.DateFull >= '10/5/2016') 
    AND (t1.DateFull <= '11/9/2016') 
    AND t2.createdBy <> 21
GROUP BY 
    t1.DateFull
ORDER BY 
    DateFull
```

Results:

```
DateFull                 | Washes
-------------------------+-------
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000  | 1231
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000  |  466
2016-10-10 00:00:00.000  |   84
2016-10-12 00:00:00.000  |   75
```

Expected results:

```
DateFull                 | Washes
-------------------------+-------
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000  | 1231
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000  |  466
2016-10-07 00:00:00.000  |  655
2016-10-08 00:00:00.000  |   23
```

Comment: But `createdBy` **can't** be 21 if it doesn't exist at all. You have a logical issue you need to tackle first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are three approaches.  As I started to answer the question, I realized that subtly different things might be happening.  Probably all three of these will work, but the first may not always work.

I suspect you just want an additional `NULL` comparison:

```
SELECT t1.DateFull, COUNT(t2.ContainerWashedDate) as Washes
FROM DateLookup t1 LEFT JOIN
     factContainerWash t2
     ON t1.Datefull = t2.ContainerWashedDate
WHERE t1.DateFull >= '2016-10-05' and
      t1.DateFull <= '2016-11-09' and
      (t2.createdBy <> 21 or t2.createdBy is null)
GROUP BY t1.DateFull
ORDER BY DateFull;
```

Or, alternatively, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.DateFull, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN createdBy <> 21 THEN t2.ContainerWashedDate END) as Washes
FROM DateLookup t1 LEFT JOIN
     factContainerWash t2
     ON t1.Datefull = t2.ContainerWashedDate
WHERE t1.DateFull >= '2016-10-05' and
      t1.DateFull <= '2016-11-09'
GROUP BY t1.DateFull
ORDER BY DateFull;
```

It is also possible that moving the condition to the `ON` clause does the work you need:

```
SELECT t1.DateFull, 
       COUNT(t2.ContainerWashedDate) as Washes
FROM DateLookup t1 LEFT JOIN
     factContainerWash t2
     ON t1.Datefull = t2.ContainerWashedDate AND t2.createdBy <> 21
WHERE t1.DateFull >= '2016-10-05' and
      t1.DateFull <= '2016-11-09'
GROUP BY t1.DateFull
ORDER BY DateFull;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you used the t2.CreatedBy in the WHERE clause, you made the LEFT JOIN becoming an INNER JOIN. How about something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.DateFull
    , COALESCE(t2.Washes, 0) AS Washes
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ContainerWahsedDate
        , COUNT(ContainerWahsedDate) AS Washes
    FROM
        factConainerWash
    WHERE
        ContainerWahsedDate BETWEEN '2016-10-05' AND '2016-11-09'
        AND CreatedBy <> 21
    GROUP BY
        ContainerWashedDate
    ) t2
    LEFT JOIN DateLookup t1 ON t1.DateFull = t2.ContainerWahsedDate
WHERE
    t2.DateFull BETWEEN '2016-10-05' AND '2016-11-09'
```